# Regarding container of form recogniser,OCR and labeltool containers

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

We are trying to use the container preview of form recogniser,OCR and labeltool and have following questions:

1. Is there any software which can help us to classify similar kind of documents. This will help us to categorize document and create training dataset
2. Is there any way to give the model user-defined name. Following is output from model query API.It is difficult to tie it back to different kind of models:

```
{
    "modelId": "f136f65b-bb94-493b-a798-a3e8023ea1b5",
    "status": "ready",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-05-06T21:35:58+00:00",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-05-06T21:36:06+00:00"
}
```

3. I can see models file stored in \output\subscriptions\global\models where /output directory shared container in  docker compose file. Is it possible to import this model to new containers.

   - Models  have json and gz file with the same nae as model id
   - I am also attaching docker compose file for your reference
4. Is there way to fine tune or update same custom model(same model id) with model training data
5. We were also trying the labeltool but it only takes Azure blob as input. Is it possible to provide input same as we do for training of form recognizer.
   We are struggling to get this setup and if it is not resolved we might to start looking to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Following are answers to your questions:

1. To classify documents you can use custom vision to build a document classifier or use text classification and OCR. In addition you can use the Form Recognizer train without labels run it on the training data and use the cluster option within the model to classify similar documents and pages in the training dataset.
2. Friendly Model name is not yet available in Form Recognizer, its a future feature on our roadmap but not available yet.
3. Models can't be copied between containers, you can use the same data-set to train a model in a different container. Models can be copied between subscriptions, resources and regions when using the Form Recognizer cloud service.
4. Each train creates a new model ID in order not to overwrite the previous model you can't update existing models.
5. Form Recognizer v2.0 release is not yet available in containers, only Form Recognizer v1.0 release is currently available in containers. Form Recognizer v2.0 will be also available in containers shortly. When using containers release all the data remains on premise and the labeling tool once available for the v2.0 containers release will also take as input a local or mounted disk and not blob.

Thanks ! 
Neta - MSFT

Comment: Hi Neha,Thanks  for reply. Could you please elaborate on 1st point process.Suppose we have 1000+ pdf forms in a folder and then we want to classify similar forms.(This will help me create training dataset for form recognizer)How we can proceed with this requirement based on above suggestion.